# Issue On Getting Panel With in Bootstrap Inactive Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://www.bootply.com/6Bsc21Ggnj) and let me know if there is a way in JavaScript/jQuery to get the width of Bootstrap Panel in an inactive Tab?

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart</a></li>

  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Check The Chart Tab</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and this returns `0`

```
var chartWidth = $(".panel-body").width();
console.info(chartWidth);
```

Comment: its returning -30 for me

Comment: @DestinationDesigns, Thanks but how to get the actual size?

Comment: Do you want the `width` of the `panel-body` or the whole `tab`?

Comment: @DavidDomain, Thanks I need just the `.panel-body` width

Answer (score 0):

it would appear you can get the width ot the panel when the tab is clicked:

```
$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function () {
    var chartWidth = $(".panel-body").width();
    console.info(chartWidth);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Destination Designs but u it is a liitile bit late since I have to create some charts on the panel on load

Comment: yea im actually curious about this so I'm looking at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events to see how to best trigger this

Answer (score 0):

Just use `shown.bs.tab` event and set the `visibility` of the current tab to `hidden`.

When your done with what ever you want to do, put it back to `visible`.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var crntTab = $($(e.target).attr('href')),
      panelBody = crntTab.find('.panel-body'),
      panelBodyWidth = 0;
  // Check if you have a panel-body.
  if(panelBody.length > 0) {
    crntTab.css("visibility", "hidden");
    panelBodyWidth = panelBody.innerWidth();
    // Do what you have to do.
    panelBody.each(function(i,v) {
      $(v).text("Foo loves Bar.");
    });
    // When you are done.
    crntTab.css("visibility", "visible");
  }
})
```

If you want to make this tab the active tab just add.

```
$("a[href='#profile']").tab('show');
```

Comment: Thanks David but I need to do this on load without any click event, how can I do it that case?

Comment: Made an edit. Just add the last line under the event listener.

Comment: tab-panes are set to display: none; and display: block when active. so...technically your inactive panes are not in the DOM on load right? So you need to somehow change the visibility of the pane either by click or on document.ready to get the width and then change the visibility back